# Spring boot @Getmapping redirection error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my application I wanted to use get mapping to redirect me to topicform.html file. I do not know why this specific situation is not working. In other mappings it works fine.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("newTopic")
@RequestMapping("/forum")
public class TopicsController {

...

  @GetMapping("topicform")
    public String newTopic(Principal principal, Model model){
    ...
    }

   @GetMapping("topic/{id}")
    public String showTopic(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Topicform is not working but when I want to redirect to the topic it works fine.

Intelij even not mapping me it.

Html files directory looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Missing "/" before topicform? You can try in your browser. You pfobably using "/forumtopicform" as endpoint.

Comment: Post all the code.  Also what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@GetMapping("/topicform")
public String newTopic(Principal principal, Model model){
...
}

@GetMapping("/topic/{id}")
public String showTopic(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
...
}
```

Comment: @ProGramer no, it is not working. The funny thing is that "topic/{id}" section works fine and many others but only topicform is not.

Comment: I solve that. It should be added to the dictionary.